# Trouble with jQuery UI Bootstrap radio buttons on Rails

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I believe that I have successfully integrated [jQuery UI Bootstrap](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) with Rails thanks to [this gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails), as the datepicker appears to be working correctly.

I am trying to generate a radio buttonset, and am having some trouble with both the jQuery UI functionality and the Bootstrap styling.

I have the following erb:

```
<div class="ui-buttonset">
  <%= f.radio_button :available, true, checked: true, class: 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' %>
  <%= label :available, 'Available', value: true, class: 'ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-left' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :available, false, class: 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' %>
  <%= label :available, 'Unavailable', value: false, class: 'ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-right' %>
</div>
```

With the javascript `$('.ui-buttonset').buttonset();` and `$('button').button();`, but nothing happens when I hover, click, etc. There is no change to the UI element, the checked attr, or anything else as far as I can tell. Do I need to handwrite javascript for this functionality, or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I have tried to paste [the jQuery UI example](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#example-1) directly into my markup with no luck. In order to get the datepicker to work, I had to `//= require jquery-ui` in my application.js and call `$(el).datepicker();`, which it does not appear should be necessary with this gem. Any ideas on how to test whether or not the appropriate files are being included?

Comment: I have confirmed that the appropriate css and js files are being loaded. When I call `$('#radio').buttonset();` (from the [jQuery UI example](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#example-1)), it applies the appropriate classes to the elements. Still no styling or functionality though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be [a conflict between Bootstrap and jQuery UI Bootstrap](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap/issues/71). Perhaps it is better to manually add javascript directly to to my `vendor` directory instead of relying on gems.